# How to use the install command with a heredoc

Tags: bash, shell, heredoc

I'm trying to convert an install script to use the `install` command rather than creating a file and running `chmod +x` against it. This is the script right now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

install_target=/usr/local/bin/my_prog
volatile_path=/this/path/could/change

cat << EOF > "$install_target"
#!/usr/bin/env bash

"$volatile_path/some_other_executable" "\$@"
EOF
chmod +x "$install_target"
```

What I'd prefer to do is something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

install_target=/usr/local/bin/my_prog
volatile_path=/this/path/could/change

install "$install_target" << EOF 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

"$volatile_path/some_other_executable" "\$@"
EOF
```

What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: What does `install` expect on standard input? Is it the contents of a text file? A quick look at `install --help` might give you an idea.

Comment: The version of install I expect my users to have available just provides literal usage from `--help`, no explanation. However, the man page provides a bit more explanation, and appears to be asking for file names, not file contents, so I suspect you helped me answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, and assuming you're using a BSD version of install (GNU `install` has full help shown by `install --help` whereas BSD only shows basic usage) I think this is what you want to be doing:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

install_target=/usr/local/bin/my_prog
volatile_path=/this/path/could/change
temp_file=/tmp/$0.$$.$RANDOM

cat << EOF > "$temp_file"
#!/usr/bin/env bash

"$volatile_path/some_other_executable" "\$@"
EOF

install -bd "$temp_file" "$install_target"
rm -f "$temp_file"
```

Untested, but using [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) should remove the need for a temp file:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

install_target=/usr/local/bin/my_prog
volatile_path=/this/path/could/change

install -bd <(cat << EOF
#!/usr/bin/env bash

"$volatile_path/some_other_executable" "\$@"
EOF
) "$install_target"
```

Comment: Yep, you beat me to it :+1:

Comment: My preference would be to use `install` to create a null file with the desired name and permissions, and then echo to it (instead of messing with a temp file).  That still doesn't achieve the ultimate goal of doing this in one step, unfortunately.

Comment: @PaulGalbraith I've learned a lot in the past 5 years. No need for a temp file!

Comment: In your heredocs, the `"$volatile_path/some_other_executable" "\$@"` would be rendered as `"/some_other_executable" "$@"`. Putting `"` around the heredoc keyword prevents bash from expanding those and allows the `"\$@"` to lose the escape.

Comment: But then `$volatile_path` is not expanded. And that `cat` was not useless, it's sending text into the fd file.